# How gmail system get mail faster? 

Tags: gmail, system

how does gmail work?
does gmail uses sockets for instant replay or ping/echo for new mails or make requests in interval time.

Comment: probably something similar to the way facebook gives notifications/live stream i would imagine. Possibly an implementation of a Node.JS type of technology.

Comment: Take a look at this link. It might be what you are looking for.... http://blog.benstrong.com/2010/11/google-and-microsoft-cheat-on-slow.html

Comment: This blog post explains why: http://blog.benstrong.com/2010/11/google-and-microsoft-cheat-on-slow.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that it´s with the **Observer Pattern via push** with JavaScript and (maybe, I don´t know) Java Backend.

When there is a change in the server, the push notify to the view and the new mail appears.

Regards.